# App crashed on IE 11 after migrating from Meteor 1.2.1 to 1.5.2

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor

I have migrated my Meteor App from 1.2.1 to 1.5.2. App works perfect in all browers except IE 11.
Here are all the errors I am getting in IE browser console:

```
[SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'for'
modules.js (516,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
es5-shim.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
promise.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
babel-runtime.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
ecmascript-runtime-client.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
ejson.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
diff-sequence.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
geojson-utils.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
id-map.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
random.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
mongo-id.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'DiffSequence' of undefined or null reference
minimongo.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
check.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Random' of undefined or null reference
retry.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
ddp-common.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Symbol' of undefined or null reference
reload.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
ddp-client.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'DDP' of undefined or null reference
ddp.js (14,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'LocalCollection' of undefined or null reference
allow-deny.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'AllowDeny' of undefined or null reference
mongo.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
reactive-dict.js (20,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'ReactiveDict' of undefined or null reference
session.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
jquery.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
twbs_bootstrap.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Random' of undefined or null reference
localstorage.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'MongoID' of undefined or null reference
observe-sequence.js (19,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
blaze.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Random' of undefined or null reference
accounts-base.js (20,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Random' of undefined or null reference
srp.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Accounts' of undefined or null reference
accounts-password.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
oauth.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Random' of undefined or null reference
accounts-oauth.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Accounts' of undefined or null reference
service-configuration.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'OAuth' of undefined or null reference
facebook-oauth.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'ObserveSequence' of undefined or null reference
spacebars.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Blaze' of undefined or null reference
templating-runtime.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Template' of undefined or null reference
templating.js (14,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined or null reference
accounts-ui-unstyled.js (19,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Template' of undefined or null reference
facebook-config-ui.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Accounts' of undefined or null reference
accounts-facebook.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
aldeed_simple-schema.js (20,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'SimpleSchema' of undefined or null reference
aldeed_collection2-core.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Collection2' of undefined or null reference
aldeed_schema-index.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Collection2' of undefined or null reference
aldeed_schema-deny.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
http.js (19,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
rajit_bootstrap3-datepicker.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
cfs_base-package.js (20,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'DDP' of undefined or null reference
livedata.js (14,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_storage-adapter.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_filesystem.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
dschulz_jquery-qrcode.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
mizzao_timesync.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Accounts' of undefined or null reference
mizzao_user-status.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Mongo' of undefined or null reference
tmeasday_publish-counts.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
ostrio_logger.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Logger' of undefined or null reference
ostrio_loggerfile.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
kadira_dochead.js (19,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
mizzao_jquery-ui.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Mongo' of undefined or null reference
lai_collection-extensions.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Mongo' of undefined or null reference
dburles_mongo-collection-instances.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Session' of undefined or null reference
angular-meteor-data.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
interwebs_ui-sortable.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
dangrossman_bootstrap-daterangepicker.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$' of undefined or null reference
fragaria_angular-daterangepicker.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Template' of undefined or null reference
copleykj_stripe-sync.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
dynamic-import.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Blaze' of undefined or null reference
ui.js (14,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Blaze' of undefined or null reference
dotansimha_accounts-ui-angular-moded.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference
webapp.js (18,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EJSON' of undefined or null reference
cfs_data-man.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_file.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_tempstore.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_access-point.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_upload-http.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_collection.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_collection-filters.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'FS' of undefined or null reference
cfs_worker.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Retry' of undefined or null reference
autoupdate.js (19,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Mongo' of undefined or null reference
global-imports.js (3,1)
SCRIPT5009: 'meteorInstall' is undefined
app.js (1,1)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'check' of undefined or null reference
mdg_validation-error.js (17,1)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

pbastowski_angular-babel.js (1579,5)](url)
```

I have used `pbastowski_angular-babel` for migration. What could be the issue, App works fine in Edge also.

Is there any other better way for migration of Meteor app from 1.2.1 to 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work through the errors one by one and fix them, although it looks like many are repeated. For example

```
[SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'for'
modules.js (516,1)
```

This is probably a `<label for="someId">` where someId is the id of the element such as a radio button. The new way to do this is wrap the label around the radio element, like this:

```
<label><input type="radio".....> This is a choice </label>
```

As for this one, adding babel will probably fix it

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference es5-shim.js (17,1)
```

Comment: How can I add babel?

Comment: Use this command: `npm install --save-dev babel-cli` For more information see https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @StormTrooper How did you fix the issue `Unable to get property 'meteorInstall' of undefined or null reference es5-shim.js (17,1)`?